# Is there a way to integrate the log of a function, f(x) in Matlab without defining eg l = log(f(x)?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have the following code:

```
x = 0:0.001:2.5;
gamma_l = @(x) 2*x;
```

And I want to integrate the following:

```
integral( log(gamma_l), 0 , 0.6 )
```

But it gives me the error:

> Undefined function 'log' for input arguments of type
>   'function_handle'.

I know that I could just define:

```
gamma_l_l = @(x) log(2*x);
integral( gamma_l_l, 0 , 0.6 )
```

Because it works in this way. However, I would like to know why the first case does not work. And if there is a way to integrate the function without defining a new function.

Comment: The first case does not work because `log()` requires numbers as inputs, and you are not giving it a number, you are giving it a function handle. The logarithm of a function handle is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, @Ander! So do you think that the most efficient (only) way is to define another function? Isn't there a way to define composite function _inside_ the integral?

Comment: Gnovice's answer is how you should handle this ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable `gamma_l` is an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and the [`log`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log.html) function is not designed to accept [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) as an input. Instead, you need to define a second anonymous function that *evaluates* `gamma_l` for a given value, then passes the numeric result to `log`, like so:

```
result = integral(@(x) log(gamma_l(x)), 0, 0.6);
```